# What is the generic way to parse combined min max in panda python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

How can I parse correctly and generically the following kinds of operations in Panda dataframe?

```
IF(data['var1'] = 100, 3.5, MAX(2.3, MIN(data['var1'], 3.4)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`numpy.maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) and [`numpy.minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'var1':[100,3,2.4,2]})
print (data)
    var1
0  100.0
1    3.0
2    2.4
3    2.0

data['new']=np.where(data['var1'] == 100, 3.5,np.maximum(2.3, np.minimum(data['var1'],3.4)))
print (data)
    var1  new
0  100.0  3.5
1    3.0  3.0
2    2.4  2.4
3    2.0  2.3
```